# Cleaning a list of URLs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel let's say, I have a VERY long list of URLs.  Some are displayed correctly - `example.com` or `example.au` or `example.ca.us` but others are displayed as `example.com/index.php=` or `example.com/taxid/15443/Default.aspx` or something even more complicated.

Can anybody think of a way I can create a list where everything is the top-level domain?

Comment: By "top-level domain", do you want "sub.example.com" to become "example.com"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list of URLs begins in cell A2, use this formula in an empty cell in row 2:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1),A2)
```

Now copy downward as far as needed.

Comment: That campe very close to doing what I need, thats awesome - thank you.  Need to clean up a little more data (not everything had my www's and http's but this was great!